# mysql-connector-python : execute(multi=true) with multiple insert statements+multiple-row-syntax

Tags: python, mysql, sql, mysql-connector, mysql-connector-python

I have a string constructed with multiple insert statements and insert statement with values given in multiple-row syntax. Is it possible to specify multiple insert statements along with values given by multiple row syntax for execute(multi=true) in mysql-connector-python? For. e.g below is the string concatenated with the insert statements, first statement with multiple row values:

```
operation = 'INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c) VALUES(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9)(11,22,33),(44,55,66),(77,88,99); 
      INSERT INTO tb2_name (a,b,c) VALUES(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9);
      INSERT INTO tbl1_name (col1,col2) VALUES(col2*2,15);
      INSERT INTO tbl1_name (col1,col2) VALUES(15,col1*2);
      INSERT INTO tbl2_name (col1,col2) VALUES(col2*2,15); 
      INSERT INTO tbl2_name (col1,col2) VALUES(15,col1*2);'
for result in cursor.execute(operation, multi=True):
    print reslut.row_count
```

Comment: Did you actually try the code?

Comment: yes, I tired it. It works with multiple row values.